# want to run and stop service with activity android

Tags: android, android-service

I am wondering if i can do this, i want to implement a service that will be called when activity launches and should run at regular intervals, and when i stop the activity by closing or pressing back the service should stop and alarm manager should not invoke service before the activity relaunches.
One more thing i want to send some data on which service can operate and give results back to activity.
currently i am doing like this.....

```
class MyService extends Service{

}

class MyScheduler extends BroadCastReceiver{

//Here alarm manager and pending intent is initialized to repeat after regular intervals.

}

class MyActivity extends Activity{

 onCreate(){

    //here i am binding the service

 }

}
```

MyBrodcastReceiver is added into manifest

please help and suggest how to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

for starting:

```
this.startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

for stoping:

```
this.stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

for having intervals create a service that calls a BrodcastReceiver periodically like the following sample:

in your service:

```
// An alarm for rising in special times to fire the pendingIntentPositioning
private AlarmManager alarmManagerPositioning;
// A PendingIntent for calling a receiver in special times
public PendingIntent pendingIntentPositioning;

@Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();

            alarmManagerPositioning = (AlarmManager) getSystemService
                    (Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            Intent intentToFire = new Intent(
                    ReceiverPositioningAlarm.ACTION_REFRESH_SCHEDULE_ALARM);

            pendingIntentPositioning = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    this, 0, intentToFire, 0);



        };


@Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

            long interval = 10 * 60 * 1000;
            int alarmType = AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP;
            long timetoRefresh = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            alarmManagerPositioning.setRepeating(alarmType,
                    timetoRefresh, interval, pendingIntentPositioning);

    }
```

Comment: how the broadcast receiver will recieve intent data?

Comment: will alarm manger not continuously running and make service running all the time?

Comment: i want service to stop as soon as activity destroys.

Comment: So stop it when your Activity stopped. Use my sample