# how to stop a service from an activity

Tags: android

I am trying to unregister my service from another activity using the following approach, but it doesn't do anything.

This is my code:

```
    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            updateUI(intent);
        }
    };


    public void resetnetmon(View view) { // reset NetworkStats

        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
        stopService(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

my service's class name is **BroadcastService.java**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code for **Stopping/starting** a service:

```
stopService(new Intent(this, BroadcastService.class));

startService(new Intent(this, BroadcastService.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

For stop service with an activity:

```
this.stopService(new Intent(this, YourServiceName.class));
```

If you want to know more detail refer this question also [want to run and stop service with activity android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16249202/want-to-run-and-stop-service-with-activity-android)